# Selenium - "Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I know there are many older threads, on this site and others, for this exact error when trying to use Selenium to manage Chrome.  However, I have been trying endlessly, and without luck, to get a basic script in Powershell working.  I have stepped through, multiple times, ensuring that all prereqs are met, all required files are in the correct locations, and that I am not missing something 'dumb'.  Yet, for the life of me, I cannot get this to work.

First, the basic PS code:

```
$workingPath = "D:\Dev\Selenium"
Add-Type -Path "$($workingPath)\lib\netstandard2.0\WebDriver.dll"
$SiteUrl = "www.google.com"
$chromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver
$chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL($siteURL)
```

This fails, with:

```
Error: Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager; For documentation on this error, please visit: 
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location"
At line:5 char:13
+             throw "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"}
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Error: Exceptio...river_location":String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error: Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager; For documentation on this error, please visit: https:// 
   www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location"
```

Again, this is a classic error.  Selenium has a single, albeit not overly useful, page dedicated to this specific error, and there are many other instances of it throughout the internet.  However, my issue remains.

To show that the prereqs are in place, as well as some other relevant local system info, I wrote up the following basic PS script, ran it, and the output is also included below.

[image]

I'm really at a loss as to what else to do here, so any input is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create instance of ChromeDriver but with specifying path to your Chrome executable.

```
$chrome = [OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver]::new("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  The syntax is wrong.  It just throws an error that the file can't be found.  It's not permissions either as I am running as admin and can cd no issue.

Comment: Please replace the path with the path to not chrome but chromedriver.exe . You can get it by unzippin nupkg file same where you got the dll probably.

Comment: Hi, so chromedriver is already in the same parent directory.  Referencing back to my code in the OP, are you suggesting adding another -Path type, and setting the path to chromedriver explicitly?

Comment: Under .NET CLI on the far right side there is Download package. Download , unzip and find WebDriver.dll. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver   This is 4.18 so it shouldnt ask for argument as in previous versions. I will try it coming weekend and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I already have the web driver.  All of that has been done.  Take a look at the screenshot of PS above.  I wrote a script to output all of the relevant files, showing among others, the dll.  No versioning issues either.